# Angular 2 routing redirects in some cases, in others does not

Tags: angular

I use Angular 2 routing in my application. Everything works fine throughout my application, but in one component something weird is happening. This is my sign up component. First, I check in ngOnInit() if localStorage has a user token, then I do the following `this.router.navigate(['/page']);` This is working perfectly fine. 
Then, I have a submit user registration form

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.signUpService.newUser(form)
    .subscribe(
       success => {
          console.log("user successfully created");
          this.router.navigate(['/page']);
       },
       error => {
         console.log("error");
         this.userFailure = true;
      }
);}
```

I can see that when my authentication service returns a success/error the corresponding action happens but my router does not work in this case, I just stay on the registration component and it does not refresh or anything, all the input stays in the corresponding fields. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: try with "this.router.navigate(['/' + url])". If possible add console error also

Comment: What value does ``this.returnUrl`` have when you enter the ``success`` handler?

Comment: @AnnaPohorielova I changed it both to have ['/page'] and the issue stays the same

Comment: If there are **any** javascript errors, routing will break.  It does not have to be related to routing.  Are there any errors getting thrown in your developer console?

Comment: @Michael do not have a single error there